# Checking if boundaries of two geometries touch using PostGIS

Tags: postgis, postgresql, spatial-join

I am fiddling around with this dataset http://s3.cleverelephant.ca/postgis-workshop-2020.zip. It is used in this workshop http://postgis.net/workshops/postgis-intro/spatial_relationships.html.

I have two geometries in the same table `nyc_neighborhoods`.
I want to know if the `nyc_neighborhoods` geometry with the name `Tremont` touches the `nyc_neighborhoods` geometry with the name `South Bronx`.

How would I do that with the `ST_Touches()` Function?

```
SELECT * FROM nyc_neighborhoods AS neighbor1
JOIN nyc_neighborhoods AS neighbor2
ON ST_Touches(neighbor1.geom, neighbor2.geom)
WHERE neighbor1.name = 'Tremont' AND neighbor2.name = 'South Bronx';
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply move the function into the `SELECT` - it returns a `BOOLEAN`:

```
SELECT ST_Touches(neighbor1.geom, neighbor2.geom) AS touches
FROM   nyc_neighborhoods AS neighbor1
CROSS JOIN    -- verbose but preferred, you could use a , <comma> here
       nyc_neighborhoods AS neighbor2
WHERE  neighbor1.name = 'Tremont' AND neighbor2.name = 'South Bronx'
;
```

---

A plain `CROSS JOIN` between tables is a delicate business as it returns a cartesian product between them - here however, the explicit filter conditions limit the compared set to one row each.

Comment: However, your query *does* work, and is perfectly valid! If you get no result rows, you two geoms don't touch.

Comment: Yes, I figured that when checking the spatial relation with your query. That returns false there too. Crappy input data ;)

Comment: @Stophface remember that these spatial relations are narrowly defined rules on the geometric predicates, e.g. `ST_Touches` may just check differently than expected. Digging into the [*DE-9IM*](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/DE-9IM) and its application in the set of relationship functions helps tremendously in bug-tracking. Apart from that, coordinate inprecision is a common issue, introduced by the fact that a value can hold 15 digits of precision, and is subject to floating point rounding.

Comment: That DE-9IM is a valuable source. Thanks a lot for the hint!